# Best way to extract neuronal spike times from a noisy signal / voltage meaurement

Tags: matlab, signals, noise

I'm a neuroscientist, and not a very good one. My colleague has kindly provided me with a noisy voltage measurements of the PY neuron of the [Stomatogastric Ganglion](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Stomatogastric_ganglion) of the lobster.

The activity of this neuron is characterised by a slow depolarised plateaux with fast spikes on top (a burst).

Both idealised and noisy versions are presented [here](http://s11.postimg.org/9c2bpdy77/image.png) for you to peruse at your leisure.

It's my job to extract the spike times from the noisy signal but this is so far beyond my experience level I have no idea where to begin. Fortunately, I am a total ninja at Matlab.

Could someone kindly provide me with the name of the **procedure, filter or smoothing function** which is best suited for this task. Or even the appropriate forum to ask such an asinine question.

Presumably, it needs to increase the signal to noise ratio? The problem here seems to be determining the difference between noise and a bona fide spike as the margin between the two is quite small.

---

### UPDATE: 02/07/2013

I have tried the following filters in Matlab with mixed results. It's still very hard to say what is noise and what is a spike.

Lowpass Butterworth filter,
median filter,
gaussian,
moving weighted window,
moving average filter,
smooth,
sgolay filter.

Comment: If you don't have time constrains, you may use wavelet transform and try to determine a detail level in which the spikes appear rather than the noise. Matlab has a builtin wavelet package with graphical interface that is quite easy and intuitive to use, and you can check if it is good enough for separating your spikes. Otherwise you may try to use ICA or NMF to estimate the original source (denoised signal).

Comment: (Note: ICA and NMF would work properly better if you use more sensors to estimate the original sources. If you can change your data so that you can have more meters used in different places in the human head you may be able to unmix the sources using those techniques.)

Comment: Thanks Werner, you've given me a lot to think about. I did plot the frequency spectrum using the FFT and there are no discernible peaks, just what looks like noise across all frequencies.

Comment: The FFT problem is that you don't know exactly the window size to use that may be optimal to extract the frequencies. You may check this using a brute force algorithm, or someone else may help with a better approach for determining the FFT window size, but anyway if you have enough computer power a continuous wavelet transform is better.

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. Looks like I got some research to do.

Comment: This is a quite good signal processing problem since the noise ratio is very high and probably intersect with the frequency in which you want to extract. You should ask for specialists help on this area (you will probably find them at electric/electronic engineering) at your university, they would probably like to help/collaborate with you in this issue since this would easily become a paper for both you and them. Sometimes we have some people from health doing research or even some students doing some disciplines with us. But anyway, my bet is on the continuous wavelet to solve this.

Comment: You are welcome. I would be glad to hear what solution worked when you outcome this.

Comment: Will do, i am working on wavelets as we speak...

Comment: Ok guys, so removing the signal from the noise just wasn't possible. There was just too much interference so we used a hack. We recorded the nerve output from the neuron and matched the peaks in the nerve to the peaks in the neuron. Viola!

Comment: hahaha well done, although I am not a neuroscientist to catch what you did exactly, happy that you managed to overcome it x)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an adequate response for stackoverflow - but one way of increasing a signal to noise ratio in your case is to average parts of the signal.

1. low pass your signal to remove noise (and spikes), and find the minima of the filtered signal (from your image, one minimum every 600 data points). Keep the indexes of each minimum,
2. on the noisy signal, for each minimum index, select the consecutive 700 data points. If you have 50 minima, you should have a 50 by 700 matrix,
3. average your matrix. You should have a 1 by 700 vector.

By averaging parts of the signal (minimum-locked potentials), you will take advantage of two properties: noise is zero-mean (well, it should be), and the signal of interest is repetitive. The first will therefore decrease as you pile up potentials, and the second will increase. With this process however, you will lose the spike times for each slow wave figure, but at least have them for blocks of 50 minima.

This technique is known in neuroscience as event-related potential (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-related_potential). It may not fit perfectly your signal, or the result may not give nice spikes, but you may extract the spike times for some periods of interest (given the nature of your signal, I would say that you would need 5 or 10 potentials to see an emerging mean activity).

There are some toolboxes that do part of the job (but I would program it myself given the complexity of the task). These are [eeglab](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/eeglab/) or [fieldtrip](http://fieldtrip.fcdonders.nl/). They have a bunch of filter/decomposition options too, as well as some statistical features.

Comment: Thanks for this Magla, I will get back to u ASAP.

Comment: Ok guys, so removing the signal from the noise just wasn't possible. There was just too much interference so we used a hack. We recorded the nerve output from the neuron and matched the peaks in the nerve to the peaks in the neuron. Viola!

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for the followup and good luck for your project!